# Is there a verb for attacking someone's mind (psychic damage)?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In gaming nomenclature, when you use fire damage, you burn. When you use cold damage, you freeze. When you use holy damage, you smite. And so on.

What's a good verb for using psychic damage, i.e., making a psychic or mental attack on someone? For the purposes of this question, assume that you are doing something to invade another's mind for a wide variety of possible (negative) effects.

Comment: The problem is that mental attacks in gaming can result many different things: *confusion*, *forgetfulness*, *stupidity*, *shock*, *paralysis*, and so on. There isn't a single, overall effect in the same way that there is with other types of damage. Were you thinking of something in particular?

Comment: *Traumatize*, perhaps?

Comment: ... or  *lobotomize*?

Comment: he's mind-melding with x

Comment: I'll clarify in the question @JasonBassford. I primarily intend for a broad verb for nearly all of what you described. Fundamentally, anything that is a detrimental mental effect.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly the psychic damage does to the victim? Fiction uses different verbs depending on what happens or how it feels, eg: psionic blast (from D&D or MtG) “blasts” and psybeam (Pokémon) “shoots”. Usually though a generic word is used, like “the victim was *hit* by a psychic attack”.

Comment: Edit should be coming in soon, @Laurel. It's descriptive of a psionic attack with no physical component. Purely mind-to-mind.

Comment: The word you mentioned, “invade,” seems perfectly appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Metaphorically at least, it could be said that psychic damage [**short-circuits**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short-circuit) the synapses in another person's brain:

> Merriam-Webster
>
> transitive verb
>
> **1** : to apply a short circuit to or establish a short circuit in
>   **2** : BYPASS
>   **3** : FRUSTRATE, IMPEDE
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to become shunted by a short circuit • The radio *short-circuited*.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but it carries a machinery connotation.

Answer (score 1):

The attacker [**fuddles**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuddle) the victim, who becomes **fuddled** or  **befuddled** as a result. It’s a practical choice of words, because *fuddle* has so many established variants, e.g. *fuddlement*, *fuddlesome*, which can be applied to related states and properties.

Also, *fuddlement* is externally observable as a disconnection between stimulus and appropriate response. It doesn’t require an underlying “theory of mind” to understand.

Comment: This is a fair choice, since its somewhat archaic status isn't much of a problem in the context of gaming nomenclature. However, the word itself does sound a bit ... silly? The phrase "Fuddle Damage" just doesn't ring nicely.

Comment: @Tanthos The value of *fuddle* lies in its closeness to a much plainer English word, and with a little skill in programming you can easily exploit this. For example, the victim of a *fuddle attack* might be *fuddled in the head*. An attractive victim might be an *easy fuddle* and a hard case might be *a complete mother-fuddler*. It’s *fuddlin’ obvious*, I’d say.